# Changing flag in other document when ttl reached in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, ttl

I'm having two collections: `Devices` and `Registrations`.

When I add device then I populate `Devices` with appropriate entry and create document in `Registrations` with ttl. After one hour entry expires in `Registrations` but I would like to additionally set status flag in `Devices`.

Is there an option to create kind of 'function' that would change such flag for a given device after reaching a ttl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [**Change Streams**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) 
and [**invalidate event**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#invalidate-event).

There's also [spring data mongodb support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#change-streams).